# Flask app doen't register jwt.user_lookup_loader, Flask-JWT-Extended

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt-extended

I have a Flask app with blueprints. It worked just fine, but than I decided to use `flask_jwt_extended` to handle tokens. It is said in docs that I can decorate method with `jwt.user_lookup_loader` to have `current_user` working. But for some reason calling `current_user` ends up with an error:

```
You must provide a `@jwt.user_lookup_loader` callback to use this method
```

But it is there, in the same blueprint. There is also a method, decorated with `@jwt.user_identity_loader` and it works perfectly well.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from . import rpc, jwt
from flask_jwt_extended import current_user, jwt_required

bp = Blueprint('login_bp', __name__)

@jwt.user_identity_loader
def _user_identity_lookup(user):
    return user.id

@jwt.user_lookup_loader
def _user_lookup_callback(_jwt_header, jwt_data):
    identity = jwt_data["sub"]
    user = rpc.cache_service.get_user(identity)
    if user is None:
        return None
    return UserSchema().load(user)

@jwt_required()
@bp.route("/logout", methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    rpc.cache_service.forget_user(current_user.id)
    return {"status": "OK"}
```

jwt here is JWTManager, initialized with my app:

```
jwt = JWTManager()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    app.config.from_mapping(JWT_SECRET_KEY=os.environ["JWT_SECRET_KEY"])
...
    jwt.init_app(app)
...
    with app.app_context():
        from . import login_bp
        app.register_blueprint(login_bp.bp)
```

This code is basicly from the documentation examples:

https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/automatic_user_loading/

and I can't see what the problem might be (

Link to the repo:
https://github.com/GreenBlackSky/COIN/blob/master/api_app/app/login_bp.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorators are in the wrong order. `@bp.route()` needs to come before `@jwt_required()`, otherwise it tries to evaluate the `logout` method when a request comes in before it decodes the JWT in the request.